# empty & not empty word constraint search

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I created word constraint on element repository

```
  <constraint name="repository">
    <word>
      <element ns="http://lmpublishlearning.com" name="repository"/>
    </word>
  </constraint>
```

we have some document in which element repository value is blank like

```
 <lmp:repository/>
```

Now in our search application how I can pass above type to get blank value document with word constraint. I try below different case but not able to get result.

rs:q=repository:''&rs:pageLength=10&rs:start=1&rs:sort=relevance"
  rs:q=repository:""&rs:pageLength=10&rs:start=1&rs:sort=relevance"

Answer (score 2):

It might meet your requirements to write a custom constraint:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_97085

that returns

- a [cts:element-word-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-word-query) on a tagged value that's not empty
- a [cts:element-value-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query) on a tagged value that is empty

Hoping that helps,